# Controlling the order in which Gulp concats javascript files

Tags: gulp, gulp-concat

I am having trouble controlling the order in which my javascript files are concatenated with Gulp.  I've tried gulp-order but it doesn't seem to work. I just started using Gulp, so I am sure (hoping) this is an easy solution.  I did notice some SO posts on renaming the files with numbers...I do not want to do this. Thank you.

```
gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    gulp.src('starter_app/static/backoffice/js/vendor/*.js')
        .pipe(order([
            'excanvas.js',
            'respond.js',
            'js.cookie.min.js',
            'bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js',
            'jquery.slimscroll.min.js',
            'jquery.blockui.min.js',
            'jquery.uniform.min.js',
            'bootstrap-switch.min.js',
            'app.min.js',
            'dashboard.min.js',
            'layout.min.js',
            'quick-sidebar.min.js'

        ]))
        .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('starter_app/static/backoffice/js'));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    gulp.src([
        'excanvas.js',
        'respond.js',
        'js.cookie.min.js',
        'bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js',
        'jquery.slimscroll.min.js',
        'jquery.blockui.min.js',
        'jquery.uniform.min.js',
        'bootstrap-switch.min.js',
        'app.min.js',
        'dashboard.min.js',
        'layout.min.js',
        'quick-sidebar.min.js'
    ], {
        cwd: 'starter_app/static/backoffice/js/vendor'
    })
    .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('starter_app/static/backoffice/js'));
});
```